# Where can I configure deployed application versions limit in weblogic 12.2.1.3.0?

Tags: weblogic, redeploy

Where can I configure deployed application versions limit in weblogic 12.2.1.3.0 ? I get this error.

> weblogic.management.ManagementException: [Deployer:149113]Cannot deploy or redeploy application "****" because the maximum number of application versions (2) for application "****" has been exceeded. Currently deployed versions are: "****, ****"

Comment: i'm afraid you cannot. Webogic Server supports only 2 versions of the same application deployed at a time. You have to remove the oldest to deploy your new version.

Comment: You can check the Oracle documentation for this restriction:https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24443/redeploy.htm#DEPGD274